# How to build thrift with -fPIC

Tags: thrift, fpic

I have some reason to pack libthrift.a/libthriftnb.a into a shared lib(instead of use so files directly), so I should build them with -fPIC.

I build thrift like this:

```
./configure --prefix="$PATH"/../thrift-0.8.0_build;
make;
make install;
```

How can I change to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run configure like this.

```
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC CXXFLAGS=-fPIC
```